# What is the geometric interpretation of the leading coefficient in a quadratic equation?

Tags: geometry, quadratics

What is the geometric interpretation of the leading coefficient in a quadratic equation? It is clear we do not call it a slope or elasticity or derivative of the quadratic equation.

Comment: Which coefficient?

Comment: do you mean the coefficients a,b and c in $ax^2+bx+c=0$? or rather mean $p(x-q)^2+t=0$

Comment: I mean "a" simply here.

Comment: Someone tells me it is called marginal impact of the independent variable on the dependent variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading coefficient effects the curvature. Taking the second derivative yields just $2a$, so this determines if the curve is convex or concave, and how much so.

Comment: Yes, but it is "2a", not "a" here.

Comment: The sign is the same as the sign of a, so it still determines convexity vs concavity. The number a is directly proportional to the second derivative, so the magnitude directly impacts the curvature as well, and this is the geometric meaning of it. If you're asking for a "name" for a alone, you can call it the leading coefficient (assuming you've written the equation down) or the coefficient of the highest term.

Comment: Yes, and do we have the name for "a" in geometric terms.

Comment: No. The interpretation of $a$ geometrically is that it impacts the curvature. As far as I know, there is no name which specifically refers to $a$ and also reflects this geometric meaning. If there is one, it would be sufficiently obscure to be relatively useless.

Comment: The direction of the optimum? HAHA